# How to improve classes ? Issue with inner classes [Android]

Tags: java, android, optimization, inner-classes

I'm using **Android Studio** to develop my app. I have two activities that does the same thing (except a parameter value) and I have an inner class inside which does the same thing too in the other activity. My inner class extends AsyncTask for background downloading. But, if I extend my second activity from my 1st activity, I can't do task.execute(), I will need to extend AyncTask too,and extending from two classes impossible in Java.. Here's my code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private TextView title;
private List<User> myList;
String query_url;
MyAdapter myAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    recycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recycler.setLayoutManager(llm);

    //create and execute new task
    AsyncDL task = new AsyncDL();
    task.execute();

}

//background download
private class AsyncDL extends AsyncTask<Object, String, Integer> {

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Object... params) {
        tryDownloadXmlData();
        return null;
    }

    private void tryDownloadXmlData() {
        try {
            URL xmlUrl = new URL(query_url);
            myXMLPullParser myCustomParser = new myXMLPullParser();

            //fetch & parse data
            myList = myCustomParser.parse(xmlUrl.openStream());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Integer integer) {
        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(), myList);
        recycler.setAdapter(myAdapter);

         RecyclerItemClickSupport.addTo(recycler).setOnItemClickListener(new RecyclerItemClickSupport.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClicked(RecyclerView recyclerView, int position, View v) {
                User user = myList.get(position);
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Details.class);
                myIntent.putExtra("user", user);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });
        super.onPostExecute(integer);
    }
}
```

}

I don't really know if it is possible to reuse an activity's code like that, thanks !

**EDIT:** new piece of code

```
ProductAsyncTask task = new ProductAsyncTask(getApplicationContext(), listview, QUERY_URL, productList, myCustomAdapter);
task.execute();

listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            User currentUser = myList.get(position); //error here
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Detail_User.class);

            myIntent.putExtra("currentUser", currentUser);
            Log.i("INFO", "Loading extra data for transfer...");

            startActivity(myIntent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Why don't you place the asynctask in a different file and make it public so they can both use it?

Comment: I tried, but my async task uses my list of user and my recycler view from my activity.. from that can we do something ? And I think I've read once that AsyncTask must be used as inner class but not sure about that.. @TimCastelijns

Comment: @Jay the last part of your comment is wrong. It is not at all necessary that asynctask should be inner class

Comment: You need to decouple your classes, put your asynctask somewhere separate and pass the data to it that it needs, and use callbacks to return data to the caller.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me Vivek, @TimCastelijns an example code would be nice please, I'm will try it as soon as I can, I will guve feedback once done.

Comment: @TimCastelijns thank you for helping, since  I had a break I wasn't working on my project, please post it as an answer, so I can accept it, thanks for helping guys !

Comment: Is your problem solved then?

Comment: @TimCastelijns after some tests I'm currently having some issue, My listview is showing, but my list of user seems empty, I'm having this : java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0, i added some code to show